Laptop updating by CMD
Can I fully upgrade or update my laptop by CMD like new Windows, sometimes I am unable to install it from Microsoft Windows and I haven't DVD disk or Bootable USB, So, am I able to do this in an easier form and how I?

Welcome to AskUbuntu The question is unclear and confusing. "upgrade or update my laptop" and "I haven't DVD disk or Bootable USB" suggests that you want to install Ubuntu directly onto the hardware ('bare metal'). But "sometimes I am unable to install it from Microsoft Windows" suggests that you wish to use WSL to run Ubuntu virtualized within your existing Windows install. Please edit your question to clarify.

sudo apt-get update   then issue    sudo apt-get upgrade

Does this have anything to do with Ubuntu?!
